# SuiteScript 2 join queries

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

and thanks, I need to bring columns from a joining table in SS 2. The form that I am using for the column is 
                searchModule.createColumn({
                    name: "class",
                    join: "CUSTRECORD_NWP_ITMPRICE_ITEM"
                }),
where the main table and the ancillary table are joined on the "item" column. I use a plugin to get the code for queries by creating a saved search and the plugin provides the code. It has always been correct but this time not so much. the saved search works fine but the code produces nulls for those columns. What is the correct form for creating join columns in SS 2?

thanks, any help is appreicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that my queries were bringing back arrays for those columns and the method utility function that I created to facilitate extracting data from the resulting query object did not account for the arrays and returned null. I have to modify the utility to account for that and it will be fine thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: extending on this many columns return arrays, it is the methods for getValue and getText that return the corresponding values. What the answer was, was to build a column name which is obtained in the query as "join.name" as "join_name" replacing the period with the underscore than the getValue etc worked.